# Merge arrays inside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I've got an issue. I had a part of code.

```
    foreach ($query->result() as $server)
    {
        //Prepare host and port to pass to mon script
        list($host, $port) = explode(':', $server->address);

        $GS = new Source($host, $port);

        $result[$server->id]['id'] = $server->id;

        if(!$result[$server->id] = $GS->get_details())
            unset($result[$server->id]);
    }
```

Inside this loop i have array width ID number:

```
$result[$server->id]['id']
```

After this i have this:

```
if(!$result[$server->id] = $GS->get_details())
        unset($result[$server->id]);
```

This code checks if server online and destroy empty array. It generate new array, that rewrite my array, created before.

So how i can merge this two arrays in loop with minimum code? thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as follows

```
if($result[$server->id] != $GS->get_details())
    unset($result[$server->id]);
else
    $result[$server->id]['id'][] = $server->id;
```